# How do I enable the PHP HTTP PECL extension on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, pecl

I have an installation of XAMPP version 1.7.3 on Windows 7 x64. I want to enable the [PHP HTTP extension](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php). How do I go about doing so? That is, where to I get the DLL, register it, etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [How to get php_http extension working on PHP version 5.4 with Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777361/how-to-get-php-http-extension-working-on-php-version-5-4-with-windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, download the PECL module from the php website.

Then unzipp it and copy the file php_http.dll in your PHP extension folder. Then edit your php.ini file (c:\WINDOWS\php.ini) and activate the module :

```
extension=php_http.dll
```

Comment: This solution worked. Thank you. For others running in to the same problem, with XAMPP 1.7.3 use the version from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ labeled "php_http-5.3-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip (2009-11-26 07:19 -0800)".

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. Whenever I add php_httpd.dll to my php.ini I get the error "The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." Any ideas?

Comment: I had to use: php_http-5.3-svn20091125-vc9-x86.zip (2009-11-25 01:17 -0800)

Answer (score 5):

As you are on an earlier PHP Version, you can get the build from: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

If you upgrade to XAMPP 1.8.3, which uses PHP 5.4, then you should take a look at the closed bug about this found at: **bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62056**

As per details in the bug comments; I downloaded the ts (thread safe) version for XAMPP 1.8.3 from **github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads** and listed as "php_http-1.7.4 -5.4-vc9-x86.zip"

The latest builds can be found at: **windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/1.7.5/**

Amoung those links you should find a version specifically for what you need.