# How to get php_http extension working on PHP version 5.4 with Windows?

Tags: php, windows, iis, pecl

Anyone know how I can get the php_http extension working on php 5.4.5 on windows?

I am trying to upgrade to PHP 5.4.5 on my windows machine (running off IIS). The project I am working on has a dependency of the php_http extension (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php)

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a downloadable DLL file anywhere for a 5.4 compatible version of this extension (see http://php.net/manual/en/http.install.php). Installing via pecl doesn't seem to work for me either, I end up getting this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58531

Does anyone know where I can get a DLL for this, or can provide me with other options for getting this extension set up?

Note: 5.3 works fine using the DLL linked to here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php#109498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pierre Joye [provides](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/) Windows builds of various PECL extensions for new versions. If it's not there (which at the time of writing it isn't) you have no option but to get the source ([here](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http)) and build it yourself.

Sorry.

Being that [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is much more readily available, and can do pretty much everything (if not actually everything) that the HTTP extension can do, I would suggest that you look at migrating your project towards using cURL instead.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had checked Pierre's listing. Figured it may come down to building myself, cheers.

Comment: +Good answer but `php_http` is still very handy

Answer (score 3):

Internet posts from August 2012, I bear greetings from THE FUTURE.

In the time since this question was asked and answered, a new [Windows PECL extension directory](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/) appeared. It's more up-to-date than Pierre's, but it only has 2.x releases of pecl_http; anything written for 1.x will need a rewrite (see [the new docs](http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http)). Nonetheless, the new directory looks like your best bet for PHP 5.4 and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

As of this post Dec 2015 there appears to be a new locations for all sorts of Windows compiled pecl and other PHP Extensions.

Its only a couple of weeks after PHP7 was release and there are already PHP7 compatible extensions available here so I have to assume this location is being activley maintained.

Start your search [HERE](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/)