# HttpRequest in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I have a program that used to run well before upgrading to xampp 1.8.1.
Now I get the Fatal error : Class HttpRequest not found in c:\xampp...

My OS is Win7. Is there any package I should install?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Uninstall it (remove completely from disc) and re-install it.

Comment: [This question may help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777361/how-to-get-php-http-extension-working-on-php-version-5-4-with-windows). You need the [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http) package for your version of PHP (5.4.x). If you can't find it already compiled somewhere you will have to build it yourself from the [source](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/http/).

Comment: You seem to be right Mike yet it seems building pecl is a complicated process, are there any easy instructions!

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, I installed an older version of XAMPP. Everything works fine now.